# Change DatePickerDialog style, to show a calendar instead of the scroller picker

Tags: java, android, android-theme, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

Im using a `DatePickerDialog` on my app, and when it shows it looks like this

[image]

Im trying to change the look of it, to look like [this one](https://www.android-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/DatePickerDialog-theme-3.png)

This is how i declare my picker:

```
DatePickerDialog datepicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT,this,year,month,day);
```

According to a tutorial i was reading, if we pass `AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT` it should display the calendar like i want, but it does not work. Do i need something else?

**Edit**

Seems it might be an issue with Huawei(brand of the phone i was using) according to [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/p9/help/date-picker-android-nougat-t3559624)

Comment: What version api do you use ? You can't do it in old versions.

Comment: compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26

##

and im running in an phone with android 7.1.2

Comment: Hey, was this issue resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

From the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) -

> When the **DatePicker_datePickerMode** attribute is set to **calendar**, the month and day can be selected using a calendar-style view while the year can be selected separately using a list.

According to [datePickerMode doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#DatePicker_datePickerMode) -

> Prior to the L release, the only choice was spinner. As of L, with the **Material theme** selected, the default layout is calendar.

So, if you are using the material theme in your Activity, then pass 0 in themeResId. This will make the dialog use the parent context's default alert dialog theme.

```
DatePickerDialog datepicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
0 ,this,year,month,day);
```

Otherwise, you can use [Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert) or [Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert).

```
DatePickerDialog datepicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
R.style.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT,this,year,month,day);
```